# find $n$ such that $n! + n^2 + 2$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

I have encountered this problem in a Romanian mathematical magazine: Find $n$ prime such that $n! + n^2 + 2$ is also prime. Of course, if $n = 2$ does not work and, if $n > 3$, we get that $n! + 2\equiv 2 \pmod {3}$. Since $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {3}$ (if $n\neq 3$), we get that $n! + n^2 + 2\equiv 0 \pmod {3}$, which cannot be true. So, that means that $n = 3$ is the only solution.

But I was wondering: can we extend this to find every natural natural $n$ such that $n!+ n^2 + 2$ is prime? I have tried to work out with congruences, but the only thing I have managed to find is that $n\equiv 3 \pmod {6}$. After using Wolfram Alpha, I found that $n = 15$ and $n = 21$ are solutions. Can you help me?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123527/discussion-on-question-by-andu-eu-find-n-such-that-n-n2-2-is-prime).

Comment: On the one hand, the only natural numbers $n$ upto $7\ 000$ for which $n!+n^2+2$ is prime are $0,3,15,21$ , on the other hand for $n=111$ there is no small factor (I did not find a factor yet) and algebraic factors or similar ones would be a great surprise. Probably there is another prime of this form, but it must be huge.

Comment: No further prime for $n\le 10\ 000$

Comment: No further prime for $n\le 14\ 000$. The case $n=111$ splits into the $36$ digit prime factor $$130588177082578275280473550696780739$$ and a $146$ digit prime factor. It is a semiprime.

Comment: Finally : Note that for $n\ge 2$ , $n!+n^2+2$ can only be prime if $n^2+2$ is prime , otherwise $n^2+2$ would have a divisor $d$ with $1<d<n$ which would also divide $n!+n^2+2$

Answer (score 1):

**Long comment**:

For $n^2+n!+2$ to be prime $n^2+2$ must also be prime, otherwise a factor of $n^2+2$ less than $\sqrt{n^2+2} < n+1$ would divide $n!$ and hence $n^2+n!+2$.

$n^2 + n!+2$ is prime also tells us that $3$ must divide $n$, otherwise $n^2 +n!+2 \equiv 1+0+2 \equiv 0\pmod 3$.
Since $n^2 +2$ is prime we can also say $n$ must be odd. So $n$ is of the form $3(2k+1) = 6k +3$.

Both $n^2+n!+2$ and $n^2+2$ are primes that are of the form $4l+3$.